buscar un cliente base de datos seleccionar el cliente guardar el ID del cliente en la base de datos estoy usando laravel 10 vue 3 composition api
'quien me puede ayudar estoy haciebdo un buscador de cliente no se como pasar el cliente_id a la base de datos, lo selecciono y todo pero en el request no lo recibe. soy nuevo en vue3
este es mi scrip vue
const clientes = ref([]);
~
const traerCliente = () => {
if(buscador.value.length >= 3){
        axios.get('/buscarcliente', {
            params: {
                buscador : buscador.value
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            clientes.value = response.data;
            console.log(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error =>{
            console.log(error.response.data);
        })
    }
    
};

const clienteseleccionado =  (cliente) => {
    if(cliente!=''){
       var idcliente =  cliente.AR1Codigo;
    }
     console.log(idcliente);
}

const form = useForm({
    buscador: '',
    cliente_id: ''
});

const submit = () => {
    form.post(route("reservas.store"));
};


"`<input type="search" 
   id="buscador"
   v-model="form.buscador"
   @keyup="traerCliente" />

`
<ul>
   <li  @click="clienteseleccionado(cliente)"v-for="cliente in clientes" :key="cliente.id"> 
    <a href="#" >{{ cliente.AR1Linea1+' '+cliente.AR1Nombre.toUpperCase() }}</a>
</li>
</ul>





Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
